# Get values from another workbook and apply a prefix based on column name

Tags: vba, excel

I know this question is too simple. But, I don't know how I will apply my logic in vba excel. I want to get or pull the data from one workbook (Book1.xls) to another workbook (Book2.xls). I need to get the values in Column A and B of Book1 and assigned it in Column A (Book2 - Details). Then, for every value in Added column, it should have a prefix of "Addition:", same with Deleted column, for every value in Deleted column, it should have a prefix of "Deletion". The range of Column A and B in Book1 can be change.
[image]

Thankyou.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick

```
Sub AdditionDeletion()

    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Set ws1 = Workbooks("Book1").Worksheets("Compare")

    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    Set ws2 = Workbooks("Book2").Worksheets("Details")

    Dim current As Long
    current = ws2.Range("A" & rows.count).End(xlUp).row + 1

    Dim i As Long
    For i = 3 To ws1.Range("B" & rows.count).End(xlUp).row
        ws2.Range("A" & current) = "Addition:" & ws1.Range("B" & i).Value2
        current = current + 1
    Next i

    For i = 3 To ws1.Range("A" & rows.count).End(xlUp).row
        ws2.Range("A" & current) = "Deletion:" & ws1.Range("A" & i).Value2
        current = current + 1
    Next i

End Sub
```